# Machine limit analysis of $\sqrt {x^2-a^2}-(x-a)$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Let $L(x)=\sqrt {x^2-a^2}-(x-a)$. I've been messing around with this equation on the calculator and found out that for certain values of $x$, the equations behave as $x \gg a$. Considering only for $x > a$ this is what i've found for 2 cases of $a>0,a<0$ avoiding imaginary calculations for $x<a$.

$$ L(x)=a+O(\frac{1}{x})sgn(a) $$

$$sgn(a)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & \mbox{if $a > 0$}\\
        -1 & \mbox{if $a < 0$}\end{array} \right.$$

At some point within the machine limit of the calculator, when it is considered that $x \gg a$, $L(x)=0$. This makes sense in the way in the limiting case $L(x)=\sqrt{x^2}-x=0$, but on a graph it seems to continuously have a gap between $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ and $x-a$, and this is what i expect by my definition, but it gives me zero instead. I wanted to know if it was possible to compute the threshold $x_{th}$, knowing machine limit $\varepsilon$, that satisfies $L(x \geq x_{th})=0$? If so, could you compute it? P.S. This isn't homework, go easy on those hints.

Just wanted to add, on a TI-30X calculator this happens around $ln(x)-ln(a) \geq 10$.

Comment: You mean you want an answer not just a hint?

Comment: Hints are welcome, but i'm afraid of the hints because this isn't my area of expertise. An answer would be what i'm looking for. Either way try to answer this question the best way you think is fit.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the effect of roundoff error.   When $x$ is large enough, the computed value of $x^2 - a^2$ is the same as $x^2$, and then the square root of that is $x$.  For even larger $x$, $x - a$ is the same as $x$, and that's when you get $0$ as the final result.